# Check calling of endpoint in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have following code and I want to check whether `/account/logout` service was called, how to implement it?

```
it('should log out', () => {
  // It will be good to check if application returned
  // to login page and if /account/logout endpoint has been called.
  cy.get('[alt="user_avatar"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
    .get('[data-cy=cy-btn-signout]')
    .click();

  cy.wait(500)
  cy.url().should('include', '/login');

  cy.pause();
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to check that? Your user doesn't care which endpoints are getting called, I wouldn't couple an E2E test to the API if I could avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check whether `/account/logout` service was called, how to implement it?

Assuming its a post call:

```
  cy.server();
  cy.route('POST', '/account/logout').as('logout');
  cy.wait('@logout');
```

## More

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html